# Google Cloud Endpoints and Android, an Async uncertainty

Tags: android, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using `Google Cloud Endpoints` to generate client libs, to comunicate with the app on `AppEngine`.
Generated libs don't handle async process, they just provide a **synchronous method** to call a function on the server.

`AsyncTask` is the easier solution, but also the worst one.
`IntentService` looks like a mess to control.

`Retrofit` spoiled me with its few lines of code to do everything, I wish I could use it with `Endpoints`.

What **pattern/library** can I use to speed up clientside developing? (API>=14)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take a look at Google's volley library:
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html